# Error due missing id column, I don't have it, but Django keeps asking for it. Error (1054, "Unknown column 'marca_id' in 'field list'")

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-forms, mysql-workbench

Django keeps asking me for a marca_id field while rendering a form, even when I didn't instruct my form, view or model to look for such column, I don't know what to do, this error shows when I try to click save in the render.

here's my code

Views.py

```
def CargarModelos(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ModeloForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            marca = form.cleaned_data['marca']
            modelo = form.cleaned_data['modelo']
            tipo_de_producto = form.cleaned_data['tipo_de_producto']
            
            # Primero, obtén o crea el objeto MarcaModelos y TipoProducto si es necesario
            marca_obj, created = Marcasmodelos.objects.get_or_create(marca=marca)
            # Actualiza la línea para obtener o crear el objeto 'TipoProducto'
            tipo_obj, created = Tipoproducto.objects.get_or_create(tipo_de_producto=tipo_de_producto)
            
            # Luego, crea un nuevo objeto Modelo con las referencias a marca y tipo de producto
            modelo_obj = Modelos.objects.create(marca=marca_obj, modelo=modelo, tipo_de_producto=tipo_obj)
            return redirect('modelos_lista')
    else:
        form = ModeloForm()
    return render(request, 'Compras/CargaModelos.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
class ModeloForm(forms.ModelForm):
    marca = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Marcasmodelos.objects.all(), empty_label='Seleccione una marca')
    tipo_de_producto = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Tipoproducto.objects.all(), empty_label='Seleccione un Tipo de producto')

    class Meta:
        model = Modelos
        fields = ['marca', 'modelo', 'tipo_de_producto']
```

models.py

```
class Marcasmodelos(models.Model):
    marca = models.CharField(db_column='Marca', primary_key=True, max_length=20, unique=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'marcasmodelos'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.marca


class Modelos(models.Model):
    modelo = models.CharField(db_column='Modelo', primary_key=True, max_length=45)
    marca = models.ForeignKey(Marcasmodelos, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='modelos_marca',related_query_name='marcasmodelos', max_length=20, to_field='marca', verbose_name='marca')
    tipo_de_producto = models.ForeignKey('Tipoproducto', on_delete=models.RESTRICT, related_name='modelos_tipo_de_producto', related_query_name='tipoproducto', verbose_name='Tipo de Producto', to_field='tipo_de_producto')
    
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'modelos'

class Tipoproducto(models.Model):
    tipo_de_producto = models.CharField(db_column='Tipo de Producto', primary_key=True, max_length=45, unique=True)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tipoproducto'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tipo_de_producto
```

formModelos.html

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="mb-3">
                {{ form.as_p }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="cancelButton">Cancelar</button>
</form>
```

I'm getting the data for Marca and Tipo de producto select options from Marcasmodelos(models.Model) and Tipoproducto(models.Model), and add as a keyboard input the Modelo field, I´m looking to save all of these 3 fields into Modelos(models.Model) after clicking save, but getting the error in the render as:

Exception Type: OperationalError at /CargaModelos/
Exception Value: (1054, "Unknown column 'marca_id' in 'field list'")

My database is in MySQL Workbench where I also don't have marca_id, either in MarcasModelos or Modelos tables.

Comment: Why have you set `managed` to False?

Comment: it is actually an import from an already built schema in MySQL that´s how Inspect built the models at the beginning

Comment: Okay. That makes sense.